# TCPDF - Two HTML tables side by side

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Is there a way to display two HTML tables side by side in a PDF-document generated with TCPDF?

I tried inline-CSS but neither `float: left` nor `display: inline-block` works.
I am using version 6.2.12.

Comment: What I remember about TCPDF, you should create another wrapping table around both tables and create for each of them new column <td></td>.

Comment: You should (try) to describe completely what you want in such a situation. Like how you wish each column/table to act when there is a break in the page. Once you start to think about all the different situations that can occur between a left table and a right table and the cells in each and the breaks allowed across pages you will quickly realize why floats (which are for a page) and inline-blocks (which are also for a page) do not work for *paginated* content.

Comment: Use like this <table><tr><td width="50%"><table><tr><td>Your text goes here ..</td></tr></table></td><td width="50%"><table><tr><td width="10%">Your text goes here ..</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

Answer (score 3):

You should try merging two table inside another parent table like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>data that you want to display left</td>
                 </tr>
           </table>
       </td>
       <td>
           <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>data that you want to display right</td>
                 </tr>
           </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

add this html to variable and then pass that variable into tcpdf menthod writeHTML().